# giving special characters at command line arguments

Tags: java

Hi all! I have written this program for reading command line arguments.

```
public class UseArgument {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.print("hi, ");
    System.out.print(args[0]);
    System.out.println(" How are you?");
}
}
```

I tried to send the following argument through the command line:

```
java UseArgument @!&^%
```

and it's throwing an error as follows.
Output:

```
hi, @! How are you?
```

*''%'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

```
java UseArgument @!^%
```

Can anybody explain this behavior? Does this relate to regular expressions?

Thanks.
sivakiran B

Comment: did you enter those symbols within quotes?

Comment: No, i didn't added within quotes. As u said i added them and i am getting the result.. May i know why we don't need quotes for normal strings.. apart from these for eg java UseArgument hi will work even without quotes

Comment: Because it depends on the CLI environment you're executing these commands from. Most of the CLIs interpret these special symbols as having different meanings. A simple string like 'hi' doesn't mean anything to those terminals.

Answer (score 6):

Some of the special characters you are using have a meaning to the shell from which you are launching your program. By putting the characters in quotes, you are instructing the shell not to process these characters according to their special meaning.